# Laravel completely ignoring my config file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, imagick, laravel-artisan, intervention

So, I'm trying to use Intervention Image with the Imagick driver.

I've done `php artisan vendor:publish`, and selected Intervention, and now `config/image.php` exists. I've changed `'driver' => 'gd'` to `'driver' => 'imagick'`, but nothing at all happens.

I then tried `php artisan config:cache`, same thing.
Then `composer dump-autoload`, then `php artisan cache:clear` and any other combinations of the above.

I can put literally anything in this file, fill the array with invalid syntax, junk etc, and it's completely ignored.

Is there something I'm missing? I've tried everything I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please delete *cache* folder from *bootstrap* folder and create new empty *cache* folder in *bootstrap* folder after run below command

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

The ***config:clear*** command is used to remove the configuration cache file created by the ***config:cache*** command. By default this command will delete the *bootstrap/cache/config.php* file.